# Is my algorithm about blob tracking for vehicle following correct?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, algorithms, tracking

I'm doing vehicles tracking project. The video is a one-way, no vehicles occlusion.
After doing background subtraction, erosion and dilation, I get bounding box objects for each frame, and I can find $centroid(c_x,c_y)$ from that.
So, the next thing I want to do is blobs tracking. Here is what I'm thinking on how to do the blobs tracking:

1. At first frame, store all (cx,cy,id)
2. Next frame, calculate distance each new (cx,cy) with each of old (cx,cy)
3. If `distance < threshold`, update the old (cx,cy) which qualify the formula
4. If `distance > threshold`, check if the cx,cy is `near the entry coordinate` (e.g. around x,y=0-640,0-40), if `yes` store new (cx,cy).

Is it right and possible to apply to tracking?

Comment: Looks good. Suggested alternative technique in answer.

Comment: What if the number of centroids increase or decrease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider tracking using MeanShift & Cam Shift:

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_meanshift/py_meanshift.html#meanshift

Comment: Isn't makeshift and camshift is for single tracking, how I can use the technique for vehicles?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'single tracking'? The example in the link uses Meanshift and CamShift Techniques for vehicle tracking which I believe is your objective.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm wrong.. I read some paper and it can tracking multiple objects.. But I'm still don't understand how to do it.. I'm confuse with the mathematics terms..

Comment: It sounds good, but how do you get the bounding boxes?